# How to calculate average of HTTP Request Latency in milliseconds in app metrics using PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, cloud-foundry, promql, pcf

My spring boot application is deployed in PCF. In PCF, there is App metrcis which show 'HTTP Request Count (per minute)', 'HTTP Request Latency in milliseconds' reports using PromQL query.

[image]

And for 'HTTP Request Latency in milliseconds' report, its using '(sum(rate(http_duration_seconds_sum{source_id='aaa'}[359s:15s])) by (process_type) / sum(rate(http_duration_seconds_count{source_id='aaa'}[359s:15s]) > 0) by (process_type) * 1000)' promQL query.

I don't know what is [359s:15s] in this query.

**Now I have to calculate average of HTTP Request Latency in milliseconds in given time range.
For example : I have to calculate average of HTTP Request Latency in milliseconds for between 11 AM to 11 PM.**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`[359s:15s]` is range selector with [resolution](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery). In this case, your query requests data for the last 359 seconds for every 15 seconds.

When using Grafana for visualization it is [recommended](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#use-__rate_interval) to use `$__rate_interval` instead fixed value.

Regarding the second part of the question: as far as I know, you could not query Prometheus for semi relative time windows (like 23:00 yesterday - 11:00 today).

But you could set such a time range for the grafana dashboard. Use limits: `now/d - 1h` - `now/d + 11h`. More on matter [here](https://grafana.com/blog/2022/02/03/pro-tip-how-to-use-semi-relative-time-ranges-in-grafana/).